# How do I set an form input element to hidden?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap and can not set an input to hidden.  It can be easily set to hidden with JS using

```
document.getElementById("inputCommentsBrand").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

but I would like it to be hidden by default.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputComments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Markings</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div><input hidden type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCommentsBrand" name="inputFlags[]" placeholder="Brand and Location: Sbar RH"></div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCommentsEarTag" name="inputFlags[]" placeholder="Ear Tag Color & #: Green 165"></input></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `<body onload="myFunction()">` to hide the field.

Below is the running example.

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("inputCommentsBrand").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>

<html>
  
<body onload="myFunction()">

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputComments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Markings</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCommentsBrand" name="inputFlags[]" placeholder="Brand and Location: Sbar RH"></div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCommentsEarTag" name="inputFlags[]" placeholder="Ear Tag Color & #: Green 165"></input></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of visibility:hidden
Use display:none